# Extract row data based on two columns

Tags: python, database, bash, awk

I would like to preface by saying I'm very much a beginner.

I have two txt files. One with about 1000 values in two columns (i, j) referring to paired particles which have broken. The second file contains XYZ coordinates in columns of all 4M particles where the particle tag (i or j) is the row number. I need to take the tags (i and j) from file 1 and find their associated XYZ coordinates so that I get a new file with the following format:

output:
Xi Yi Zi Xj Yj Zj

for each broken pair of particles.

I'm not sure what the best tools to use this are. I have some experience with awk and bash as well as python but I'm not getting anywhere.

file 1:

```
C6i C7j
2084974 2135208
380134 632561
416969 416972
86296 86300
2296040 2343415
493401 562376
444984 522708
405188 536773
84709 130065
```

file 2: XYZ are columns 3, 4, and 5 respectively.

```
ni    -0.139703912516E-01 -0.588106472470E-02 -0.246993537185E-01  0.240235100000E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
al    -0.137235866800E-01 -0.641882704213E-02 -0.251673100913E-01  0.534478800000E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
ni    -0.185856021576E-01 -0.152366221623E-01 -0.121702424186E-01  0.243473343750E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
ni    -0.189394000761E-01 -0.152668306704E-01 -0.124951222187E-01  0.247782468750E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
ni    -0.186657676593E-01 -0.149796823498E-01 -0.117824363740E-01  0.245485618750E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
ni    -0.183548072309E-01 -0.146581691495E-01 -0.119760428210E-01  0.262177487500E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
al    -0.179781075366E-01 -0.152651341795E-01 -0.118226752981E-01  0.476129550000E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
al    -0.184341198964E-01 -0.147587453602E-01 -0.127106194529E-01  0.509758600000E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
ni    -0.162533369485E-01 -0.349146188426E-01 -0.141615273706E-01  0.253299731250E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
ni    -0.163557464187E-01 -0.344963153936E-01 -0.143620570810E-01  0.239937831250E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
ni    -0.166373601765E-01 -0.351914412333E-01 -0.135853527002E-01  0.244891000000E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
al    -0.158054048322E-01 -0.352289094572E-01 -0.137329142337E-01  0.462249725000E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
ni    -0.405319274446E-01 -0.296567975721E-01 -0.243386549644E-01  0.254679675000E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
ni    -0.409494727711E-01 -0.296234747969E-01 -0.240603258346E-01  0.250886643750E-03  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
```

Comment: I've been trying to use awk but awk works line by line. I need to read a column value (i) then jump to that row in the other file and then jump back to the line I was on and use j to jump to a different line in the second file.

Comment: I understand the question, but can you just for clarity post the first 10 lines of file one and file two ?  That would help a lot.

Comment: I'll try :) This is my first foray into stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {xyz[FNR]=$3" "$4" "$5;next;} {print xyz[$1],xyz[$2];}' file2 file
```

Suppose that file1 is:

```
C6i C7j
2   3
6   1
```

and `file2` is the same as in your question, then:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {xyz[FNR]=$3" "$4" "$5;next;} {print xyz[$1],xyz[$2];}' file2 file1

-0.641882704213E-02 -0.251673100913E-01 0.534478800000E-03 -0.152366221623E-01 -0.121702424186E-01 0.243473343750E-03
-0.146581691495E-01 -0.119760428210E-01 0.262177487500E-03 -0.588106472470E-02 -0.246993537185E-01 0.240235100000E-03
```

How it works:

The `awk` command is given, in this order, the two files: `file2` `file1`.  `awk` implicitly loops through each line of the files.

- `FNR==NR {xyz[FNR]=$3" "$4" "$5;next;}`

  FNR is the number of lines read so far from the current file and NR is the total number of lines read so far from all files.  Thus, when `FNR==NR`, it means that we are reading the first file listed on the command line.  For that file, we save columns 3,4,5 into the array `xyz` indexed by their line number.

  The `next` command tells `awk` to skip the remaining commands and jump to start over with the next line.
- `print xyz[$1],xyz[$2]`

  If we get here, we are working on the second named file, `file1`.  We look up the coordinates for the two particles named on this line in the array `xyz` and print them out.

Comment: Thank you so much I understand this method completely and it works beautifully. Gotta start using stackoverflow more often.

Comment: Just upvoted this answer.. likes this solution too ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `product` from `itertools` together with some list manipulation

```
from itertools import product

raw_data1 = open('data1.txt').read()
"""
data1.txt holds:
1 2
2 3
"""

raw_data2 = """
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
"""

data1 = [map(int, x.split()) for x in filter(None, raw_data1.splitlines())]
data2 = [x.split() for x in filter(None, raw_data2.splitlines())]

take_coloumns = lambda x: (x[1], x[2], x[3])

for x, y in data1:
    print [take_coloumns(list(product([x], data2[x-1]))),
           take_coloumns(list(product([y], data2[y-1])))]
```

The `data2[y-1]` is because python is zero indexed, and i guess your lines are 1 indexed. The code will output:

```
[((1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (1, 'd')), ((2, 'f'), (2, 'g'), (2, 'h'))]
[((2, 'f'), (2, 'g'), (2, 'h')), ((3, 'j'), (3, 'k'), (3, 'l'))]
```

You see the idea? If you have a lot of data you should use dynamic programming to remember to line-partical corelation.

Comment: I believe I understand the concept however I'm a bit confused on the implementation. I put the name of my files in the """ next to "raw_data"? I also don't see how I could account for the fact that the xyz values I want (abc for you) are in columns 3-5. Thank you very much.

Comment: btw @John1024 has a solution with `awk`, I will just mention that a solution with `awk` will be much faster, than a solution in Python, so if you have a huge amount of data, `awk` is a better choice..

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt in bash, not the optimal solution I'm afraid, 
*Python* or *C* (maybe even *awk* ??) should be more suitable for this job

description:
input file1, col 6 is i col 7 is j ?
input file2, we need col 3,4,5 ?
because of the 4 million lines in file2, there is no way to use arrays in bash in a convenient way.

This is going to be slow, so best if you copy file2 to RAM (whatever is mounted as tmpfs is good)

```
#!/bin/bash

while read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 i j
do
    sed -n "^$i""p" file2| { read c1 c2 X Y Z ; echo -n "$X $Y $Z ";}
    sed -n "^$j""p" file2| { read c1 c2 X Y Z ; echo    "$X $Y $Z" ;}
done <file1 >output_file
```